# OpenBMC bmcweb RedFish OEM extension

Tags: openbmc

I want to try to add some OEM-specific properties in the OEM section of some resources in Redfish.

From the information I got from the Redfish Specification, Forum, and README files in bmcweb. It seems like I need to define the OEM CSDL and JSON schema to match the payload that I expected to show when the user GET the resource by Redfish, and then do the implementation in bmcweb source code, which means modifying the bmcweb directly.

I'm unsure if my understanding is correct since I thought the OpenBMC bmcweb source should not be modified directly by OEM. And should have a mechanism to add the OEM platform code into the common source code of bmcweb.

If yes needs to modify the bmcweb source code, then where do I need to define the OEM schemas? Inside a standard Redfish resource like ./static/redfish/v1/schema/Chassis_v1.xml and ./static/redfish/v1/JsonSchemas/Chassis/Chassis.json
or define them in an OEM XML and reference them in Chassis_v1.xml? And implement the OEM API in bmcweb source code after defining the OEM schema?

thank you.